# Jitter to multiple of dots, can i?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can i get `geom_jitter` with these frequencies as multiple of dots?

```
head(GOL_F_WriteCounter, 10)

Var1          Freq
1  2014-10-20   44
2  2014-10-21   64
3  2014-10-22   43
4  2014-10-23   32
5  2014-10-24   24
6  2014-10-25   18
7  2014-10-26   26
8  2014-10-27   31
9  2014-10-28   45
10 2014-10-29   30
```

my code:

```
ggplot(GOL_F_WriteCounter, aes(x= Var1, y= Freq))+
   geom_jitter()+ scale_x_date()`
```

[image]

Comment: I want to show points on 20-10-2014 until it reaches 44, 64 points until it reach number 64..etc I just want to show how active is this date compared to others

Comment: That would be ok, The idea behind this, is with jitter of points, it gives more feel about the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
d <- GOL_F_WriteCounter[
    unlist(Map(rep, 1:nrow(GOL_F_WriteCounter), GOL_F_WriteCounter$Freq)), ]
d$y <- unlist(lapply(GOL_F_WriteCounter$Freq, seq))
ggplot(d, aes(x = Var1, y = y)) + geom_jitter() + scale_x_date()
```

[image]

Comment: funny question, but howcould you make the limits as this picture?i have tried  scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2015-12-01"), end)), but it doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, i forgot, its ok, i just used dataset[1:390,]...etc and it worked fine, thanks again.